# Program resizing when connecting to MS Access database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I'm making a C# program using Visual Studio 2010 that uses MS Access database. Every time the connection opens the whole program resizes, not just the form but every control in it. Here is the code for the form which is just a part of a bigger program, this is just the login form that uses the database connection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace protowtype
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select password from accounts where username='" + txtuname.Text + "'";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            bool found = reader.Read();
            if (found == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User does not exist!");
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
                return;
            }
            if (reader["password"].ToString() != txtpass.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password does not match!");
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            this.Hide();
            Form1 medical = new Form1();
            medical.Show();
        }

        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ClinicDB.accdb";
        }
    }
}
```

The resizing of the form is triggered by the button click event specifically the connection.Open(); line. The program becomes a lot smaller in size and stays like that the whole time. I've tried locking the form and fixing the sizemode but it still happens. I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the code, maybe it's Visual Studio or my graphics card, but I'm not sure and I have no idea how this is happening.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out.  Comment out everything but connection.Open and connection.Close and see what happens.  If it doesn't resize the form, then slowly uncomment your lines and re-run until you find the line that causes the resize.

Comment: I have commented everything except connection.open(); the form still resizes. I tried running again with connection.close this time, same thing still happens.

Comment: Inexplicable.  All you're doing is running a connection.Open statement and the form resizes?  I'd try creating a new form from scratch and bringing your code into it.  Sounds like something funky happened somewhere, maybe some corruption.

Comment: So I made a very simple form from scratch, just a form and a single button, nothing else, and the only thing inside the button click method is connection.Open(); I'm pretty sure now that it's not my code, probably something with Visual Studio or something outside VS, but I still have no idea what it is.